# Django can't login the superuser in admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, registration, django-users

So , I am trying to make an register and login system . I want to customize it using the custom user model , where I can save my data and extend the model. I am using AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager to do that. The problem is I can't login in the django admin page. I created already a superuser so I can access admin section , I enter the Email and Password correct and then I have this error : **"Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."**
What my goal is , is that I want to be able to access the administration by login ( i mean fixing this red message and being able to use administration as an superuser ), and then add to the Userr model the *specialkey* field which will take place in the login view as the username in the built-in django authentication system.

This is the message error :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL1wT.png.

I hope someone helps me with this , because I can't see the problem in the code , I've been trying to fix this for almost 3 days.

***The models.py:***

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser , BaseUserManager



 class UserrManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self , email , username  , password = None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError ("Users need an email.")
    if not username:
        raise ValueError ("Users need an username")
    #if not specialkey:
     #   raise ValueError ("Users need an specialkey")

    user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username ,
        )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using = self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self , email , username , password ,  ):
    user = self.create_user(
        username = username ,
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        password = password,

    )
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.is_active = True

    user.save(using = self._db)
    return user

class Userr(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length = 60 , unique = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # specialkey = models.CharField(max_length=26 , unique = True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

REQUIRED_FIELDS = [ 'username' ,   ]

objects = UserrManager()

def __str__ (self):
    return self.username

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

***The settings.py:***

```
Django settings for reglog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '2m9*9)#@3r%9s05+8lc+7q99r0v2!+-pey_axttbn4anh=h7^4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'rlsystem',
    'website',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'reglog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'rlsystem.Userr'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'reglog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)
```

Comment: maybe generate again superuser.

Comment: @furas what do you mean?

Comment: run again `manage.py createsuperuser` to change password (and eventually login).

Comment: @furas so what i have to do is just change password for that email ? using terminal commands?

Comment: yes, first I would change password to make sure I have correct password.

Comment: @furas i just tried that , same error

Comment: I hope you are not going to use posted SECRET_KEY

Comment: umm haha to be honest i don't know what is that secret key there , i am a beginner , this is more of a projects just to get started into django and see if programming is for me , nothing professional @funnydman

Comment: Make sure super user's is_staff is equal to 1. is_staff designates whether this user can access the admin site (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Instead of password=None, I changed it to password and passed 'password=password' together with 'username=username' into the create_user functions as you see below:

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, username, password):
.......
.......

```
user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(
email), username=username, password=password)

    .......

def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
    user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(
email), username=username, password=password)


    .......
```

If you still cannot log in, run python manage.py createsuperuser and create a new superuser and try to log in with that one.

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read [`this`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) from the Django documentation.

Please confirm that the user is active is_active because if the user is not active you will get the error. I got the same error I forgot to login with user that is active

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).